# Nested "if else" statement to other "if else" doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I have this in my view:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <% if transaction.category.blank? %>
        <a ... > ... </a>
    <% else %>
        <% if transaction.to_account_id.blank? %>
            <a ...> ... </a>
        <% else %>
            <a ...> ... </a>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
.
.
.
</tr>
```

`a` elements are rather huge, so I've omitted them.

I need to check if transaction has no category, then use first condition from first `if else` statement.

If transaction has category I need to check, if it has values in `from_account_id` and `to_account_id` columns. So, I'm using another `if else` statement to check if `to_account_id` is `blank`, and if so use the first condition from second `if else` statement.

But the second `if else` statement doesn't work. In fact I see only `<tr>`s where `to_account_id` has value. First `if else` statement (with `category` check) work fine.

Also I'm wondering why `if else` in `<td>` affects the `<tr>` visibility.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you likely have another typo in your code. As is, it will not error like you're describing. Also, as is, it looks like you can easily use if / elsif / else

Comment: Yes, you're right! I had `delegate :user, :to => :account` in `Transaction` model and `has_many :transactions, :through => :account` in `User` model. So according to other conditions in `Account` model, `current_user`'s transactions were only transactions with `to_account_id` not blank. And my `<tr>`s are only for `current_user.transactions`.
Also, I've changed nested `if / else` to `if / elsif / else`. Everything works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use scopes. Than you don't have to put that much logic into your view.
You can use scopes also with associations like:

```
scope :with_categories, joins(:categories)
```

See the Rails guide here [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and a nice ASCIIcast about here [ASCIIcasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3)